# Best Way to Run Functional Tests of a WSGI Application?

Tags: python, testing, wsgi, functional-testing

I'm writing a pair of simple WSGI applications to get a feel for the standard, and I'm to the point where I'd like to test that my applications are working as expected. Now I'm trying to figure out the best way start and stop a server hosting those applications.

My first thought was to start up the `SimpleServer` from [`wsgiref`](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html) in the `setUp` method and shut it down in the `tearDown` method. Since `serve_forever` blocks, I did that work in a separate `Thread`. Unfortunately, if I use `serve_forever` to start the server, the secondary thread it's in never dies, and it turns out `threading` doesn't expose a way to kill a `Thread`.

Now I'm considering using something like this as my `run` implementation in the server's `Thread`:

```
while keep_going:
    httpd.handle_request()
```

where `keep_going` is a variable that I set to `True` in my `setUp` and set to `False` in my `tearDown`.

Is there a better way? I was hoping to write these apps and tests using just the standard library—the better to understand what I'm abstracting away when I use a lib/framework—but this seems like an awful lot of trouble.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to test WSGI applications is [WebTest](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/), which eliminates the need to spawn test servers for your app.  Instead, it allows you to do make HTTP requests to your WSGI app as method calls on a `TestApp` object:

```
>>> from webtest import TestApp
>>> from myapp import my_wsgi_app
>>> app = TestApp(my_wsgi_app)
>>> res = app.get('/')
>>> res.status
'200 OK'
>>> res.status_int
200
>>> params = {'email': 'foo@example.com', 'password': 'foo', }
>>> res = app.post('/login/', params)
>>> res.status_int
302
```

I usually have a base test class that will add a `self.app` attribute to my test cases that points to a `TestApp` instance for the WSGI app I'm testing.  So my test methods end up looking something like:

```
def test_index_page(self):
    res = self.app.get('/')
    self.failUnlessEqual(res.status_int, 200)
```

Comment: In my experience, introducing a dependency (at least for testing) on WebTest is well, well worth it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `SimpleServer` was ever intended to run in a thread.  You might be better off starting `SimpleServer` in a separate process, e.g. using the `subprocess` module in the stdlib.  Then, you can spawn/kill the process in your `setUp` and `tearDown` methods.

Comment: That's a good point, and answers my original question fairly nicely, but after looking at it some more, I think introducing a dependency on WebTest is worth it, at this point.